# AJAX variable are not reading from PHP file?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

This is my javascript that holds the function to save the file.

```
function saveMap()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  map = document.getElementById("sectorTableMap").innerHTML;
  data = '<table id="sectorTableMap">';
  data += map;
  data += '</table>';
  document.getElementById("sectorTableMap").innerHTML = data;
  //alert("done");
  //alert(data);


  if(fileName=="lastSave - RENAME") {
    return alert("Please set a file name under [CONFIG]");
  }
  else {
    //alert(data);
    //alert(user);
    //alert(fileName);
    xmlhttp.open("POST","http://pardustools.comuf.com/saveMap.php?t="+Math.random(),true);
    xmlhttp.send('map='+data+'&user='+user+'&fileName='+fileName);
    //alert(data);
    //alert(user);
    //alert(fileName);
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    //return alert("File has successfully been saved!");
    return alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
  }
}
```

This is my files that is posted too.

```
<?php
$user = strtolower($_POST['user']);
$map = $_POST['map'];
$fileName = "savedMaps/".$user."/".$_POST['fileName'].".html";
file_put_contents($fileName,$map);
echo $fileName."<br />".$map;

?>
```

This is the output I receive on the php file.

savedMaps//.html

It should be more like this

savedMaps/randomName/fileName.html

**EDIT:**

To set for the user.

```
user = "<?php $cookie = $_COOKIE['mapperlogauth']; echo strtolower($cookie['user']);?>";
```

To set for the data...
It is under the saveMap() function and starts with map.

Comment: You have to url-encode `POST` data you send

Comment: You would have to show more of the javascript.. specifically where `user` is being initialised and given a value too

Comment: @hindmost give me an example--brain dead right now.

Comment: @Pricey give me one moment please.

Comment: Why you use pure JS? Use jQuery, it make to do AJAX requests more simpler

Comment: I'm really lazy on jQuery. Guess I'm just more use to javascript and just stays with it.

Comment: @hindmost because jquery sucks in modern development compared to vanilla js

Comment: @Matt `encodeURIComponent(data)` is an example of how you can uri encode values in javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using PHP's $_POST get, you're not posting any variables, you should use $_GET in your situation, or change your xmlhttp send to post properly. *edit* you are also missing the content type header to do a successful post

*edit* You should also be aware that there is a limit on how much you can send through using the technique you're using. (which is a get, not a post, even though you specify it)

I'd also recommend looking into jQuery for cross-browser compatibility and ease of use.

*edit*

Here's some code that will allow you to pick it up via POST:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","ajax_test.asp",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("fname=Henry&lname=Ford");
```

Comment: I now see what you mean now, I lacked my header... .-. Clumsy me.. By the way I hate you (Not really just jealous you solved it in probably minutes of looking while I been an hour debugging and stuff). But thanks a lot... Wanted to get this feature done before I went to sleep...

Comment: lol, no worries. I started with xmlhttp back in 2001, learned the hard way without any documentation. Literally took me weeks to figure out how to POST ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use :

```
xmlhttp.send('map=dummy&user='+user+'&fileName='+fileName);
```

I doubt it may be caused by the encoding.

Comment: He isn't setting the xmlhttp correctly to do a post, so $_POST won't find any variables because it's actually in the $_GET

Comment: @user3036342 He is setting the POST in xmlhttp.open("POST",...); right? You are saying this is wrong?

Comment: No it's not wrong, I edited my answer to reflect that he is also forgetting to set the content type to do a successful post, so even though he specifies POST, it will go through as a GET.

Comment: @user3036342 I am also thinking that he should add the content type, but it's not compulsory.

Comment: He was right.... I did a dummy test still didn't work... Now it works. It was the header.